# Returning a variable from react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a react component as :

```
class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const module = this.props.module;
    getModuleCode(module){
       var moduleCode = 0;
       // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
       return moduleCode;
    }
    return (
      //Info to display
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I need to get the value of moduleCode within return() and assign it to a variable to do further processing. when I assigned as,

```
var moduleCode = this.getModuleCode(module);
```

it returns an undefined object. What is the correct way of returning a value from a function?

Comment: `const theCode = getModuleCode(module);`?

Comment: the problem is not clear

Comment: @Tholle sorry, edited question. Though, not working

Comment: @Harikrishnan, function getModuleCode() is returning an integer which needs to be used in render() method. How can I get that value and stored in a varible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the code in `componentDidMount` and store it in state instead.

**Example**

```js
function doCall() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("code"), 1000));
}

class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  state = { code: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getModuleCode();
  }

  getModuleCode = module => {
    doCall(this.props.module).then(code => {
      this.setState({ code });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { code } = this.state;

    if (code === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return <div> {code} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ModulesListing />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine, there is another instance like I am getting list of modules as props. I need to run a loop to get moduleCode for each module within render. In that case which could be the feasible solution

Comment: @usergs Great. That changes the question entirely. Please accept an answer to this question and create a new question if you have further issues. [You could do something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/13w4j3l6yq).

Answer (score 1):

Try calling a function in `ComponentDidMount()` as

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getModuleCode(this.props.module);
}
```

and put `moduleCode` in state so that you can receive it after it calls `didmount`.

like

```
  getModuleCode(module){
     var moduleCode = 0;
     // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
     this.setState({moduleCode});
  }
```

receiving it in render - `this.state.moduleCode`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a state and set the state in **getModuleCode** function an use it wherever you want.

```
class ModulesListing extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getModuleCode(this.props.module);
    }

    render(){
       const module = this.props.module;
       getModuleCode = (module) => {
          var moduleCode = 0;
          // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
          this.setState({moduleCode})
       }
       return (
            const {moduleCode} = this.state;
            //Info to display
        );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getModuleCode must reside outside render function and binded to "this" contex through *bind* or *arrow function*

```js
class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  getModuleCode = (module) => {
   const moduleCode = 0;
   // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
   return moduleCode;
  }
  render(){
   // render
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `var moduleCode = this.getModuleCode(module);` in your render function, you will have to define `getModuleCode(module)` as a method in the component class and not in the render function.

```
class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  getModuleCode(module){
       var moduleCode = 0;
       // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
       return moduleCode;
    }
  render(){
    const module = this.props.module;
    var moduleCode = this.getModuleCode(module);
    return (
      //Info to display
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried this way, when printed moduleCode in console, it says **undefined**